# `if` condition not evaluating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby on Rails, and I have the following condition:

```
<% if current_user.id == character.user_id %>
  <td>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', character, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

When I do `<% current_user.id %>`, it shows the same number as `<% character.user_id %>`, but for some reason if condition is not `true`.

Comment: try appending .to_s or .to_i to both and see if that is the issue?

Comment: Can you post your migration file for "character" model please.

Comment: it works!!thank you very much! this is converting both types to string,right?

Comment: Check your migration file, too, to make sure that it isn't creating `user_id` as a string in your database.

Comment: Though @jacksonecac's tip will do the job, this is just a hot fix, since this problem will come up every time you'll try to work with the `String` id. Change the id datatype to `Integer`, or if it comes from a form here, parse it asap (e.g. in routes or in controller).

Answer (score -1):

You can try `character.user_id.to_i`. I doubt the `character.user_id` return `string value`